# Reference for convergence of Hilbert-space valued SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm fairly familiar with the literature dealing with convergence of SDEs in $\mathbb{R}^d$ but recently I've needed to use extended results dealing with convergence of SDEs in Hilbert Spaces.  However I am quite unfamiliar with the subject.
My question what is a good *reference* treating the following question:

If $W(t)$ is a cylindrical (or Q-)Wiener process with values in a Hilbert space H and $\mu_n$ as well as $\Sigma_n$ are a sequence of adapted to the filtration generated by $W(t)$ then under what circumstances does the solution to the SDEs
$$
dX_n(t) = \mu_n(t,X_n(t))dt +\sigma_n(t,X_n(t))dW(t)
$$
converge to the solution of the SDE
$$
dX(t) = \lim_{n\mapsto \infty}\mu_n(t,X_n(t))dt +\lim_{n\mapsto \infty}\sigma_n(t,X_n(t))dW(t)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Chapter 5 for projection-based methods for SDEs on Hilbert spaces:

**Second Order PDE's in Finite and Infinite Dimension: A Probabilistic Approach**
Springer-Verlag
Authors: Cerrai, Sandra
ISBN: 9783540421368

Check out Chapter 10 of the following textbook for a basic intro to convergence of discretizations (including some projection-based methods):

**An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs**
Part of Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics
AUTHORS:Gabriel J. Lord, Catherine E. Powell, Tony Shardlow
ISBN: 9780521728522

Comment: I'm not looking for the convergence of a discritization though, just conditions under which I have convergence of continuous time SDEs

Comment: I added a reference to projection methods, which are the standard way to obtain convergence results for SDEs on Hilbert spaces.